# Easiest way to obtain a Taiwan visa for a Nigerian studying in China?

Tags: visas, china, taiwan, nigerian-citizens

I'm presently in China studying and I plan to visit Taiwan very soon to attend a convention and probably visit some famous places, so I think the "visit visa" is what I need (probably stay about 8 days), asked my Chinese friend if there was any embassy belonging to Taiwan in China and he said he doesn't think so.

Searched the internet and some people said I need to go to Hong Kong to get the Taiwan visa but to go to Hong Kong I also need a visa (which I have previously been refused) and also sending my passport and visa application document to the embassy of Taiwan in Hong Kong is easy but getting it back is the hard part because they will not send it back but ask you to send somebody to get it on your behalf which can be hard because I hardly know anyone there now.

Given my situation, what's the easiest way for me to obtain a visa for Taiwan?

Comment: [Can I get a Taiwan via from China](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34421)

Comment: This is a very good, yet complex question, as Taiwan is technically _not_ a separate country from China. Both countries adhere to the one-China policy, meaning that each "country" believes to have complete control over the other one. Therefore, I believe "visa" is the wrong word to describe a way to enter Taiwan from China. I did a bit of research and found out that Nigeria _does_ have informal relations with Taiwan, which is a good start (however, like many countries, they only _officially_ recognize China as the "true" country).

Comment: Taiwan still calls them visas, except for the visa-like-things they issue to Chinese citizens. Possibly vice versa as well. But yes you won't be able to get the visa that Taiwan would issue in Nigeria because you're in China. Keep in mind China already has "one country two systems" with Hong Kong, which has different visa requirements to the mainland. So "one country three or four systems" isn't that much of a stretch, pragmatically. Now I seem to recall that the usual way this is done is via an agency in HK. Exchange of papers in the HK airport or international train station...

Comment: Seems I asked the reverse counterpart to this question a year ago: [Can a foreigner get a visa for China in Taiwan?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/can-a-foreigner-get-a-visa-for-china-in-taiwan)

Comment: @user49558: [You made me curious, so I asked.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76475)

Comment: @hippietrail1. Good question, I'm glad you asked, and 2. Don't forget Macau! It's like he's the smaller, often-overlooked brother of Hong Kong. :)

Comment: @user49558: Indeed. That's why I said "one country three or *four* systems" (-:

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know Nigerians are not given visit/tourist visas to Taiwan. It has to be a business visa not matter what. I visited last year and looking to visit again this year.